# Get email and dob for guest checkout in magento2

Tags: magento2, order-email, guest-checkout

I'm creating an extension which limits the Paymentmethodes in the checkout.
For this I have craeted the PlugIn `MethodListPlugIn` with the Methode `afterGetAvailableMethods`.

When I try to catch the dob or email in an guest checkout, (with `getQuote()` (examp. `getQuote()->getDob()`) of `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session`) I just get null.

So my question is: How can I fetch the dob and email of an guest in the checkout?

Comment: Hi, did you achieve this issues? I need it too.

Comment: probably, i can't remeber. Do you have the same problem? I can look it up for you, if you need it.

Comment: I quickly looked it up and posted it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it this way (I think, not sure if it was this project as I create this question).

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $customerAddressFactory,
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_customerAddressFactory = $customerAddressFactory;
}
public function prepareAddressDataById($addressId)
{
    $address = $this->_customerAddressFactory->create()->load($addressId);
    $addressData = $address->toArray();
    $addressData['dob'] = $address->getCustomer()->getDob();

    return $this->prepareAddressData($addressData);
}
```

( I quickly copied this out of a pretty big file and removed anything not important. So I don't know if this is plug and play ;) )

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but where guests fill up the DOB field? In my case, on guest checkout page, the DOB field isn't there, even configured to. Did you faced that too? Thankyou again.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154587/how-to-add-dob-on-checkout-page 
You can configure it in the Backend, as described in the Link:
Configuration → Customers → Cusotmers Configuration → Name and Address Options

Comment: Hi, I've setted this configuration already, but when we use anonimous (guest) checkout, the DOB field doesn't appear.

Comment: Then you may should open a Question for it by your self. I don't know what the problem could be, I'm not an expert.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/234889/how-to-add-dob-in-guest-checkout-page