# How to add DOB on checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-attribute, billing-address

I want to add customer `DOB` field in billing address on checkout page, for this I have added below code :

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="billing:dob" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Date Of Birth') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="test" name="billing[dob]" id="billing:dob" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getDob()) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Date Of Birth')) ?>" class="date-pick input-text validate-date required-entry" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" />
    </div>
</div>
```

On place order billing address saved in customer but not `DOB`.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/06/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page/

Comment: Here `DOB` is customer attribute and I want to save it with customer on order place.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it via back-end

> Configuration → Customers → Cusotmers Configuration → Name and Address Options

Then make changes in : `Show Date of Birth` = `Optional` or `required`

**Note** : It will also enable DOB field in billing and customer account registration.

Comment: When I enable, it is showing in customer account but not on checkout page.

Comment: I have checked it on my store Magento ver. 1.9.2.1 and it's showing there please revert back your changes if you have made. Then check it

Comment: I removed `billing.phtml` from my theme but still not showing.

Comment: Please clear your cache as well as

Comment: I cleared cache, but still not showing, And when I tried with my code (as in question) also not saving value in attribute.

Comment: In billing.phtml `$_dob = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_dob')` it returns nothing.

Comment: I got it, it is not working for logged in customer but it should.

Comment: You can also save/update data through observer therefore create an observer and get the post data in function and do your logic there

Comment: On which event? Can you please update your answer accordingly?

Comment: This is another question.You can ask new question I will try to answer there